# Trying to figure out python square root

Tags: python, function, parameters

How would i do the following:

Write a function compmag(r,m) to compute, and return, the magnitude of a complex number. It should take the real component of the number as parameter r and the imaginary component as m. Remember that |r + mi| = \sqrt{r^2 + m^2}.

Does Python have a square root function? How would you find it?

Comment: it does, have you checked the excellent py docs?  http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

Comment: I bet every language has the same way for computing the square root of a number...
read here, it might help
http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

Comment: it would have taken you significantly less time to type into google search box "python square root"

Comment: Python actually has complex numbers.

Comment: I think you should mention this is from your homework (http://www.csd.uwo.ca/courses/CS2120a/class3.html) and do a better job of explaining what you've tried so far.

Comment: Amazingly, if you go into Google and type `python square root` the very first result is a link to the correct Python doc.  Aren't computers nifty?  You should try this newfangled Google thingy when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either the `math` module or the `cmath` module.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(4)
2
>>> import cmath
>>> cmath.sqrt(4 + 3j)
(2.1213203435596424+0.7071067811865476j)
```

Keep in mind that the normal `math` module works only with normal numbers. You need to use the `cmath` module if you want to use complex numbers. They provide the exact same functions, so are interchangeable. The only difference is that `cmath` is a bit slower since it needs to handle complex numbers.

Comment: Note that he wants the modulus of a complex number, not the square root. It appears you can get that using `cmath.polar()[0]` function

Comment: so this would help convert the degrees, minutes and seconds?

Comment: import math
math.sqrt(degrees, minutes, seconds)
pass

Comment: @EricWilliamDolan -- Unfortunately, I don't think there's a builtin library or function to do that. You'll have to write the function yourself, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

In the [`math` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html). Just about any math-related function can be found there.

```
import math
math.sqrt(2.0)
```

Or:

```
from math import sqrt
sqrt(2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `cmath` module. The `math` module will complain if you use complex numbers. For example,

```
import cmath
x = 1. + 1j
mod, ang = cmath.polar(x)
mod
1.4142135623730951
```

Answer (score 0):

First, import math:

`import math`

Then, write the math.sqrt function:

`print math.sqrt(Your number)`